# How would I convert an argument into a string in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, position

When I run the script I enter a single argument. I want to store the argument into a variable and access it as a string. So if I enter `$ ./script foo` I should be able to access f, o, and o. So `echo $pass[0]` should display `f`

but what I am finding is that `$pass` is storing the argument as one piece
so `echo $pass[0]` displays `foo`

How do I access the different positions in the string?

```
#!/bin/bash

all=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z )

pass=$1

max=${#pass}

for (( i=0; i<max; i++ ))
do
        for (( n=0; n<10; n++ ))
        do
                if [ "${pass[$i]}" == ${all[$n]} ]
                then
                echo true
                else
                echo false i:$i n:$n pass:${pass[$i]} all:${all[$n]}
                fi
        done
done
```

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28955562/258523) covers (in part) how to index individual characters out of a string in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To spell out Etan's comment in the context of this question:

```
set -- "my password"
chars=()
for ((i=0; i<${#1}; i++)); do chars+=("${1:i:1}"); done
declare -p chars
```

outputs

```
declare -a chars='([0]="m" [1]="y" [2]=" " [3]="p" [4]="a" [5]="s" [6]="s" [7]="w" [8]="o" [9]="r" [10]="d")'
```

Comment: thank you this helped me access the different characters in the argument